# How to run multiple controllers in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

I have two controllers so far in my application. They are both annotated with @Controller, but only one of them has a main function. When I run the application, only the class with the main function shows up in the browser. When I go to the URL of the class with no main function, I just get a 404 "not found" error.

The class with a main function is:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("function")
public class Functions {
    @RequestMapping("test")
    public String test(){
       return "this is a test";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         SpringApplication.run(Functions.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I write localhost:8080/function/test, this class works fine

However, the other class:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("index")
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHomePage(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

is unfortunately not working. When I go to the browser and write localhost:8080/index I get the 404:not found-error.

It seems like only the controller with the main-function is being recognized. Does anyone know what to do to fix this?

Comment: You should be able to pass multiple classes to the run method like this:

     Object[] sources = {IndexController.class, Functions.class};
     SpringApplication.run(sources, args);

Comment: Thank you! This should work :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put the main method that launches SpringApplication in another class. Then you can have as many controller as you want, each in a new class.

Edit: Try to put @ResponseBody here:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String getHomePage(){
    return "index";
}
```

When you go on localhost:8080/index/ you should see the text "index" in your page if your controller is working.

Comment: @L01c ResponseBody is just when you want to return a JSON object not if you want to return a view

Comment: Yes, but an error 404 means the page cannot be found. By testing with ResponseBody, it helps you to know if your mapping is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You need order your code first:

1. The Application class where you have your main method and run all components.
2. As many controllers as you need, but the way Spring handle those controllers is the next

   ```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/mainFirstController")
   public class FirstController {

       @RequestMapping("/specifcFirstController")
       public String getView(){}
   }
   ...

   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/mainLogicSecondController")
   public class FirstController {

       @RequestMapping("/specifcSecondController")
       public String getView(){}

   }
   ```

The now you can call

http://localhost:8080/mainLogicSecondController/specifcSecondController

or

http://localhost:8080/mainLogicFirstController/specifcFirstController

Even you could use the same request mappings for each controller if make sense for your business logic, like:

```
/clients/showlist
/users/showlist
```

And what i read about **@ResponseBody** in the previous response, that annotation is just in the case you want to return a **JSON** object.

I hope this clarify a little bit more your idea about Spring MVC

Comment: @user3257736 have a look at this response, maybe clarify a little bit more yours doubts

Answer (score 3):

The Application class (which has your main method) should be in the outer most folder in your source hierarchy, because that is where the component scan begins. If you have any controller which is any level out of controller, spring will not be able to pick that controller during component scan.

Your src folder should have a directory structure like this

`com.example.demo
              |
              +-> controller
              |      |
              |      +--> Controller1.java
              |      +--> Controller2.java
              |
              +-> Application.java`

Answer (score 0):

If you program spring web MVC, you should configure view solver as follow:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

In the folder WEB-INF/views/jsp, you should create an jsp file "index.jsp".

You can study spring mvc in the website: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will check this out as well :) even though the problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

@RequestMapping in a class is absolute until you specify so.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/past")
public class Past {
  @RequestMapping( "/version" )
  public ResponseEntity<> version() { return "past"; }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/future")
public class Future {
  @RequestMapping( "/version" )
  public ResponseEntity<> version() { return "future"; }
}
```

.. so both classes produce together two distinct versions returning different output:

/past/version

past

/future/version

future